# How do I package an application for ubuntu apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, upstart, apt

I want to host an apt-get repository.

How do I package my application, and how do I host it in a repository for use?

The application relies on Java, MySQL, upstart and is configured to run on boot as an upstart service.

The answer should also include, how to host the package on a repository.

Ref:

- *[How do I package a Java program for Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025093/how-do-i-package-a-java-program-for-ubuntu)*
- *[How do I package Mono applications for Debian/Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539725/how-do-i-package-mono-applications-for-debian-ubuntu)*
- *[Packaging for Ubuntu - Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994008/packaging-for-ubuntu-web-application)*

Answer (score 0):

Good question, maybe a personal ppa is what you are looking for. After you finish you will have to do a $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myApp/ppa. Then you can apt-get install it.

To package your application you will need to do this in your apps directory

```
myappFolder$ dh_make -p myApp_1.0 --createorig
```

To create a original tar of your app. This will also create a Debian folder with a control file, a rules file, changelog... Change the values in these files to fit how your package should be. Specifically the control file. You will have a Depends: field where you can write in packages your application relies on such as Java and MySQL, make sure to have the same names as Ubuntu repository for these things.

goodLink https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html

Check out chapter 5 the install file and then building the package in chapter 6. I use dpkg-buildpackage usually. `debuild -us -uc` is good too look up too.

Then create an account on Ubuntu launchpad.

https://login.launchpad.net/+new_account

Sign the Ubuntu code of conduct:

https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct (take away the extra h, no reputation for more links)

Activate a PPA:

https://launchpad.net/people/+me/ (extra h)

Then follow this guide to upload the package to your ppa:

https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading (extra h)

I got these links from a great answer on ask.ubuntu. It's also got a more lengthy answer on creating a deb package.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa